# is there a way of getting the vcpu amount of a vm in azure python sdk api?

Tags: python, azure

how to get in python azure sdk `ComputeManagementClient` object the number of VCPU it has ?
code example :

```
    from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient 
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(self.credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
    vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group, name, expand='instanceView')
    vm.hardware_profile.vm_size # here i have the vm type in a string
```

## how to get from this object the number of VCPU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. After you get the VM size, then you can get the VCPU number from the exact size. The example code here:

```
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group, name, expand='instanceView')
sizeList = compute_client.virtual_machine_sizes.list(vm.location)
print(sizeList)
for size in sizeList:
    if size.name == vm.hardware_profile.vm_size:
        print(size.number_of_cores)
```

For more details, see [VirtualMachineSizesOperations class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.operations.virtualmachinesizesoperations?view=azure-python). Hope it helps.